# An explanation of Object Initialisers in C#?

Tags: c#, object

Could someone please provide a explanation of Object Initialisers in C# and examples if possible.

So far I understand that they allow you to condense instances of a class, is this correct?

Comment: Please, get a book on C# if you want to learn the language. Asking a series of questions on Stack Overflow about its basic elements is not going to get you the information that you really need. That's not what this site is for. All most people are doing is posting MSDN links anyway; you could just use the search feature on that site yourself.

Comment: I guess we will be able to use you account page as a programming guid at the end of the day ..

Comment: @Akram Shahda I am reading MSDN, but its nice to have some clarification and different views, as it helps me get a better understanding of the concepts

Comment: @Akram Shahda I will be sure to :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object initializers was added to C# in version 3, and provide condensed object initialization syntax. They are nothing but syntactic sugar, meaning they allow you to express the same code shorter than before.

Here is an example:

```
Foo foo = new Foo { Name = "John", Age = 42 };
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.Name = "John";
foo.Age = 42;
```

Have a look on the official [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

A related feature is collection initializers, which lets you initialize collections easily:

```
var names = new List<string> { "John", "Michael", "Joe" }
```

The above code is short hand for constructing a new List, and then adding each element to it. For collection initializers to work for a type, nothing more is required than a `public Add` method taking the correct type as the parameter.

Comment: Technically, it's not *exactly* equivalent to your example of instantiating then assigning.  C# object initializers are **atomic**.

Comment: @Kirk, true, but since I don't think it is important for this answer, I left the detail out (it might be more confusing than helpful for the OP).

Answer (score 0):

Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to explicitly invoke a constructor.

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

---

Refer to [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[Object Initialisers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) allow you to set the properties of an instance when you declare it. For example:

```
class House
{
    public int Rooms { get; set; }
    public int PeopleLiving { get; set; }
}
```

Then using this:

```
House h = new House { Rooms = 4, PeopleLiving = 5 }
```

Simply sets these values when you create the object, a bit like a constructor where you can choose which properties to set. You can also use a constructor as well:

```
House h = new House("10 Some Road", "Some City") { Rooms = 4, PeopleLiving = 5 }
```

---

This is actually just syntactic sugar, the compiler converts it to this equivalent C# code:

```
House h = new House();
h.Rooms = 4;
h.PeopleLiving = 5;
```

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't convert it to that code -- it's not pure syntactic sugar.  It first instantiates a temporary variable, then assigns properties to that, then assigns that temporary variable to your real variable.  In other words, the instant your variable is *assigned* it is already fully initialized.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me - it does not convert it into any C# code, but both pieces of code will have the same effect.

Comment: when you said, "the compiler converts it to this equivalent C# code", that code would be:  `House hTemp = new House(); hTemp.Rooms = 4; hTemp.PeopleLiving = 5; House h = hTemp;`.  The difference is subtle, but significant.

Comment: ^converts it to this equivalent C# code^coverts it too code equivalent to. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time without having to explicitly invoke a constructor.

All this means is that it's a convenient shortcut you can use to (hopefully) make your code more readable. The example they give:

```
Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

would be more traditionally written as:

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.Age = 10;
cat.Name = "Fluffy";
```

or

```
Cat = new Cat(10, "Fluffy");
```

The former can be more long winded, and there is a difference between the compiled code (thanks to [@Kirk Woll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/189950/kirk-woll) for the link), explained in [this post](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2007/11/24/the-atomic-character-of-object-initializers-in-c-30/). The initialiser creates a temporary variable, assigns the properties and then copies that to the real variable. Something like this:

```
Cat temporaryCat = new Cat();
temporaryCat.Age = 10;
temporaryCat.Name = "Fluffy";
Cat cat = temporaryCat;
```

The latter would (before C# 4.0 with optional arguments) require you to have a many overloaded versions of your constructor for each possible parameter combination.

Comment: No, not quite right.  Please see [this](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2007/11/24/the-atomic-character-of-object-initializers-in-c-30/).